# on hover change color

Tags: html, css

Just trying to practice on hover and dropdown in CSS. In the following code, I want that whenever the child dropdown div `.li` (green colored div with Home1 text) is hovered upon, the background color of the `ul` (which is red) should change to Blue.

Would appreciate your help.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  padding: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  text-decoration: none;
  /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); */
  display: block;
}

li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
  border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  /* [disabled]left: 0px; */
  /* [disabled]top: 0px; */
  margin-top: 5px;
  /* [disabled]float: left; */
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-small {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,204,1);
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  top: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.content-small:hover + .dropdown {
  visibility: visible;    
}

.dropdown:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  max-width: 500px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
  max-width: 500px;
  /* [disabled]max-height: 100px; */
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(153,153,153,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-small">
      Home
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Home2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Javascript is the easy solution here.

If you want to set the color of a parent element, CSS has no current selector available.

```js
$('.dropdown li').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
});

$('.dropdown li').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
html,body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    padding: 0px;
    }


*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

a {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration: none;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); */
 display: block;
}

li {
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
 border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 /* [disabled]left: 0px; */
 /* [disabled]top: 0px; */
 margin-top: 5px;
 /* [disabled]float: left; */
 list-style-type: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}




.wrapper {
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.content {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-small {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,204,1);
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    top: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.content-small:hover + .dropdown{
    visibility: visible;    
}

.dropdown:hover{
 visibility: visible;
}

ul {
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 max-width: 500px;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
 max-width: 500px;
 /* [disabled]max-height: 100px; */
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 top: 0px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 visibility: hidden;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(153,153,153,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">
   <div class="content-small">
  Home
        </div>
 <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
<li><a href="">Home1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Home2</a></li>
  </ul>
      </div>
     
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I only want to stick to CSS

Comment: @pure_coder You can't approach parent elements in CSS, only child elements and neighbours.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adamant with sticking to a CSS-only solution, you could consider styling and positioning `:pseudo` elements shrewdly.

**CSS**

```
.dropdown li {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}

.dropdown li a {
    max-width: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
    border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
    background: blue;
    z-index: 8;
}

.dropdown li:hover:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: blue;
    top: -100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
/* Start Added Styles */

.dropdown li {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}

.dropdown li a {
    max-width: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
    border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
    background: blue;
    z-index: 8;
}

.dropdown li:hover:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: blue;
    top: -100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* End Added Styles */

html,body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    padding: 0px;
    }


*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

a {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration: none;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); */
 display: block;
}

li {
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
 border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 /* [disabled]left: 0px; */
 /* [disabled]top: 0px; */
 margin-top: 5px;
 /* [disabled]float: left; */
 list-style-type: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}




.wrapper {
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.content {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-small {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,204,1);
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    top: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.content-small:hover + .dropdown{
    visibility: visible;    
}

.dropdown:hover{
 visibility: visible;
}

ul {
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 max-width: 500px;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
 max-width: 500px;
 /* [disabled]max-height: 100px; */
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 top: 0px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 visibility: hidden;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(153,153,153,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">
   <div class="content-small">
  Home
        </div>
 <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
<li><a href="">Home1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Home2</a></li>
  </ul>
      </div>
     
</div>

</div>
```

You may need to adjust values accordingly to suit your requirements.

**Disclaimer**
This is a bit of a hack and will be your responsibility to test it thoroughly. The purpose of this answer is to demonstrate the extent you'll need to go in order to achieve this only with CSS.

Although, @randy is correct in saying that parent elements can't be approached in this way with logical CSS styling. If you're not willing to explore alternatives that break away from convention, like the above, then javascript is indeed your only solution.

Comment: that looks good. Instead, how about `ul:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,204,1); 
}` to my above first code?

Comment: @pure_coder *"I want that whenever the child dropdown div .li (green colored div with Home1 text) is hovered upon..."*, the way you phrased it, I got the impression that you were specifically referring to the `a` element ("...with Home1 text") of the list item. Applying the `background-color` change in the way you mentioned above would definitely be the easiest solution though, if that'll work for you, then you should just do that.

Comment: I now get what you are saying. But in the above code, as I mentioned, the `ul` should change color from red to blue whenever the mouse is hovered upon the `li` items (home1,home2), but the moment the mouse leaves the `li` item and hovers the `ul` item (the blue background) the `ul` color should change back to red. That doesnt happens in your above code.

Comment: @pure_coder I wish you'd made that clear in your initial question:) Although I understand that, at the time, you probably thought it was obvious. If you want the `ul` to switch back to red in the manner you expect you can always extrapolate from the code above and tweak it to serve your requirements if you have the interest or time. But it seems like you've settled with the javascript solution - which is probably best in your case, as well as the quickest and cleanest. CSS-only alternatives, would always be a tad limited in such a scope.